# Symfony service factory with many children, all with different dependencies

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, factory

I am working on a very large game project in Symfony, and keep running into variations of the same problem.

I have a service that I need to separate into multiple "sub-services" because there is too much code to be contained within one class.  For instance, a custom JSON serializer handler that needs a separate handler service for each method of serialization.

I'm having trouble working out the best practice for passing dependencies between "families of services."  I would preferably like to keep all the definitions within services.yml just so things don't break in the future, but am assuming that may not be achievable.

Here's a better example - I have an "ActionQueueService" which takes a rather lengthy queue of actions from the user.  What I would like to do is create a separate class to handle each type of action, so -

- ActionQueueService // processes action queue JSON and delegates to sub-services
- AbstractAction
- PurchaseAction extends AbstractAction
- SellAction extends AbstractAction
- HarvestAction extends AbstractAction

Now if these three "actions" are defined as services they can have their own dependencies.  However, they all have to be injected into the ActionQueueService - what happens if there are 38 of them (which there will be one day).

The next logical step for me was to create ActionFactory.  Now I'm only passing in one dependency to ActionQueueService, and it can invoke any action service simply by calling -

```
$this->actionFactory->get('Harvest');
```

The problem I have is that each child has it's own separate list of dependencies.  A Purchase or Sell action would need the Character service and the ShopStock service, a HarvestAction would need the HarvestService.  Because I've decided to use a Factory method, I have to instantiate the sub-service within the factory class.  I don't want to pass every dependency into the Factory only to have that either a) inject every dependency into every child or b) handle some crazy child constructor logic.

One solution would be to pass the service container into the factory and come up with a naming convention that allows me to create the service on the fly.  I've heard that this is fairly bad practice though.  Maybe a wrapper around the service container that limits the amount of bad stuff that could be done with it.

If anybody has any ideas on how this could be solved with Symfony I'd appreciate it.  There are similar answers out there but unfortunately I don't know any languages other than PHP/Symfony.

Comment: I have a feeling that the answer lies in the second comment here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729265/symfony2-dependency-injection-container-sub-container  (CompilerPass, tags).  If so I'll mark it as a duplicate, if not I shall return.